# Data from Django-model not showing updates in Django dash app

Tags: python, django, plotly, plotly-dash

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash

from product.models import Products

app = DjangoDash("SimpleExample")
products = Products.objects.all()
to_dic = list(Products.objects.all().values("name", "price"))
keys_are = []
values_are = []
dictionary = {}
for i in to_dic:
    keys_are.append(i["name"])
    values_are.append(i["price"])
dictionary["name"] = keys_are
dictionary["price"] = values_are
opts = []
for i in to_dic:
    opts.append({"label": i["name"], "value": i["price"]})
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Label("Products"),
                dcc.Dropdown(id="pid", options=opts, value=values_are[0]),
            ],
            style={"padding": 10, "flex": 1},
        ),
        html.Div(id="gr_container", children=[]),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Graph(id="pro_graph", figure={}),
    ],
)


@app.callback(
    [
        Output(component_id="pro_graph", component_property="figure"),
        Output(component_id="gr_container", component_property="children"),
    ],
    [
        Input(component_id="pid", component_property="value"),
    ],
)
def update_graph(selected):
    message = "The option selected is :{}".format(selected)
    fig = px.bar(dictionary, x="name", y="price")
    return fig, message


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

this is my dash-graph.py file in django project, when I run the project it show bar on dashboard, but when I update database i.e. the product model it does not update the bar and show the old graph until I run the server again, also the **select box** is just for testing no use for that here. Also is their a better way write this code, like the dictionary one.

Comment: Because you don't have any api function to call repeatedly. You have put the codes directly in your Python file, which are executed only once when the project is ran and deployed and you have to stop and start every time.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I got the idea but can you give me an example. please !

Answer (score 0):

moved it to update_graph function and it works

````
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash
from product.models import Products


app = DjangoDash("SimpleExample")

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Label("Products"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="pid",
                ),
            ],
            style={"padding": 10, "flex": 1},
        ),
        html.Div(id="gr_container", children=[]),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Graph(id="pro_graph", figure={}),
    ],
)


@app.callback(
    [
        Output(component_id="pid", component_property="options"),
        Output(component_id="pro_graph", component_property="figure"),
        Output(component_id="gr_container", component_property="children"),
    ],
    [
        Input(component_id="pid", component_property="value"),
    ],
)
def update_graph(selected):
    products = Products.objects.all()
    to_dic = list(Products.objects.all().values("pk", "name", "price"))
    keys_are = []
    values_are = []
    dictionary = {}
    for i in to_dic:
        keys_are.append(i["name"])
        values_are.append(i["price"])
        opts.append({"label": i["name"], "value": str(i["pk"])})
    dictionary["name"] = keys_are
    dictionary["price"] = values_are
    opts = []
    message = "The option selected is :{}".format(selected)
    fig = px.bar(dictionary, x="name", y="price")
    return opts, fig, message```
````